# Character with longest consecutive repetition golang

Tags: go

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Result struct {
    C rune // character
    L int  // count
}

func main() {
    fmt.Print(LongestRepetition(""))
}
func LongestRepetition(text string) Result {
    if text == "" {
        return Result{}
    }
    var max Result
    if len(text) == 1 {
        max.C = rune(text[0])
        max.L = 1
        return max
    }
    var count Result
    for _, s := range text {
        if count.C == s {
            count.L++
            count.C = s
            if count.L > max.L {
                max.C = count.C

                max.L = count.L
            }
        } else {
            count.L = 1
            count.C = s
        }

    }
    return max
}
```

////
Expected
<kata.Result>: {C: 0, L: 0}
to equal
<kata.Result>: {C: 98, L: 1}

im trying to complete https://www.codewars.com/kata/586d6cefbcc21eed7a001155/train/go
Character with longest consecutive repetition
for my tests it works ok
but when im pushing to CW it cant complete corners tests
help me pls
may be i can improve my code somethere or something im misted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is too complicated. Simplify.

```
type Result struct {
    C rune // character
    L int  // count
}

func LongestRepetition(text string) Result {
    max := Result{}

    r := Result{}
    for _, c := range text {
        if r.C != c {
            r = Result{C: c}
        }
        r.L++

        if max.L < r.L {
            max = r
        }
    }

    return max
}
```

---

```
Time: 1737ms Passed: 2 Failed: 0
Test Results:
Fixed Tests
it should work with the fixed tests
Random Tests
it should work with the random tests
You have passed all of the tests! :)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to move your logic for updating `max` out of the nested `if` - and instead to the end of the loop iteration:

```
for _, s := range text {

    // ...

    if count.L > max.L {
        max = count
    }
}
```

This ensures you will have a result for not only long repetitions but also single letter occurrences.

https://go.dev/play/p/BLklmElS9Uv

Comment: yeah thanks of lot for find my mistake. Next time will use the same way to test code !